# Point to line distance in 3D using cross product

Tags: 3d, parametric

I am trying to figure out the distance of point to line in 3D using parametric equations.

By setting z0 = 0 and z1 = 1, the parametric equation of the line is
v1(x0+x1*t, y0+y1*t,t).Point P has coordinates of (xx, yy, zz). Some point on the line has coordinates v0 = (x0,y0,0).

The distance should then be D = ||(v0-P)x(v0-v1)||/||(v0-v1)||.
The numerator is the area of the parallelogram, and the denominator is the base --> giving the height of the parallelogram and thus distance.

I am unsure on the meaning of v0-v1, this is a line segment? Should it be normalized before? For some reason I seem to get the correct result for D = ||(v0-P)x(v0-v1)||.

Comment: See the Wolfram Mathworld [Point-Line Distance (3D)](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance3-Dimensional.html) article.

Comment: Difference is I do not have 2 points.
But if I am correct, d = |(v0-P) x (x1,y1,z1)|.
Because d = |(v0-P)|sin(a), and |(v0-P)xUnitary vector| = |(v0-P)||Unitary vector|sin(a) where |Unitary vector| = 1. And Unitary vector is simply (x1,y1,1).

Comment: You do have (two points for the line). The line passes through points $(x_0 , y_0 , 0)$ and $(x_0 + x_1 , y_0 + y_1 , 1)$, because the equation for your line is $\vec{v}(t) = ( x_0 + x_1 t , y_0 + y_1 t , t )$. In fact, whenever you have a parametric equation for the line, you can pick any two points (any two different values of $t$), and you'll still get the same result.

Comment: Then d = |((x0,y0,0)-P) x (x1,y1,1)| makes no sense, and I have to use 
d = |((x0,y0,0)-P) x ((x0,y0,0) x (x1,y1,1))|  /  ||((x0,y0,0) x (x1,y1,1))||?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a parametric equation for a line,
$$\vec{v}(t) = \vec{v}_0 + t \vec{v}_1 \tag{1}\label{1}$$
to find the minimum distance $d$ between point $\vec{p}$ and line $\vec{v}(t)$, we apply the formula shown in the Wolfram Mathworld [Point-Line Distance (3D)](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance3-Dimensional.html) article, noting that in this case, $\mathbf{x}_0 = \vec{p}$, $\mathbf{x}_1 = \vec{v}_0$, and $\mathbf{x}_2 = \vec{v}_0 + \vec{v}_1$ so $\mathbf{x}_2 - \mathbf{x}_1 = \vec{v}_1$:
$$d = \frac{ \left\lVert \vec{v}_1 \times ( \vec{v}_0 - \vec{p} ) \right \rVert }{ \left\lVert \vec{v}_1 \right\rVert } \tag{2}\label{2}$$

The value of $t$ where the line is closest to point $\vec{p}$ is
$$t = \frac{\vec{v}_1 \cdot ( \vec{p} - \vec{v}_0 )}{\vec{v}_1 \cdot \vec{v}_1} \tag{3}\label{3}$$

It is very often useful to parametrise the line with $\left\lVert \vec{v}_1 \right\rVert = 1$, because then $t$ is unscaled length. In that case, $\eqref{2}$ simplifies to $d = \left\lVert \vec{v}_1 \times \left ( \vec{v}_0 - \vec{p} \right ) \right \rVert$, and $\eqref{3}$ simplifies to $t = \vec{v}_1 \cdot ( \vec{p} - \vec{v}_0 )$.

Comment: Thank you! Actually, I am coding this and I get a much better fit if I put the denominator = 1, but I could not explain it.
In theory it should be the same?

Comment: @Iroxk: If $\vec{v}_1$ is an unit vector, i.e. $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$, then the denominator is indeed 1. If you just omit the division, then $d$ is given in units of $\vec{v}_1$'s length.